# Does ansible-tower also cover AWX?

Tags: discussion, tags

Simple question: does the tag [ansible-tower](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ansible-tower) also cover [AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx), the open-source core to the Ansible Tower project?

To quote from the README of the above linked project:

> AWX provides a web-based user interface, REST API, and task engine
>   built on top of [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible). It is the upstream project for [Tower](https://www.ansible.com/tower), a
>   commercial derivative of AWX.

There is no tag wiki for [ansible-tower](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ansible-tower) at this point, so I am starting this discussion to see if AWX is covered. An alternative course of action would be to create a tag alias for AWX, but that's really not strictly accurate since Tower is pretty much a commercial superset of AWX.

Comment: Both tags already exist, so you might link to the other one as well. Remember that the purpose of tags is to help people find questions. Do they need to be separate tags?

Comment: @MichaelHampton for all but the very few non-overlapping topics, I think they don't need separate tags. No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since these products are virtually identical and the question volume is very low, I've made a synonym from [awx](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/awx) to [ansible-tower](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ansible-tower). If this becomes a problem in future, we can do something else at that time...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned a tags purpose is to help find questions. That's why I believe it is contra productive to create too specific tags.

Too specific tags just mislead new users to set only the specific tag for their question. And thus question remain unanswered because nobody is watching that tag.

I believe the rules need adjustment here. I'm not able to create a tag synonym because I have not enough reputation for this tag. Probably nobody has. And with a reputation you already gain the privilege to create new tags. This has lead to a situation were we have a lot of too specific tags. Which are not really helpful to identify relevant questions.

A normal text search for `ansible-tower` returns me 46 results, a search for the tag `[ansible-tower]` 13, a text search for `AWX` 23, a tag search for `[AWX]` 4.

So in my view how `tags` can be useful tool on ServerFault none of these tags make much sense. I can view the results on one page. And doing a normal search makes it here more likely that a user finds the answer to a problem.

So to answer your question (this started out as a comment): yes, `AWX` is covered in `ansible-tower` (as they are technical to a high degree the same). And it is that because tags which are not likely to be used by the community are a bad thing for the community. Because they are not helpful.

I would like to see something like this implemented in ServerFault: if a new tag isn't actually used within a certain amount of time it gets deleted.